# Probability of winning - and some algebra

Tags: probability, combinatorics, quadratics

Here's a little probability riddle one of my friends proposed a weeks ago-

*In a game, Sheldon is going to pick three non zero real numbers and Leonard is going to arrange them as the coefficients of a quadratic equation, ax²+bx+c=0. Sheldon wins the game only if the resulting equation has two distinct rational solutions - else Leonard wins.*

**What is the maximum probability of Sheldon winning the game?**

This question has been bothering me for a while, and I've not reached any conclusions.

I tried to check the probabilities of winning by selecting random triplets {a,b,c} such as {1,2,3}, {3,4,5} etc but couldn't find any pattern.

Could someone please help me with the problem? A detailed solution, or a method to solve?

P.S.
Additional question from the comments section: 
*I think the problem is more interesting if you remove the probability.  Is there any triple of non-zero reals such that all 6 possible quadratics have distinct rational roots?*

**EDIT**-

Correctly pointed out by @lulu, the question should be rephrased as - 
"Suppose Sheldon chooses a triple of non-zero real numbers (not probabilistically). Leonard then chooses one of the 6 associated quadratics uniformly at random. What is the maximal probability for a Sheldon win?"

Comment: Where does probability enter into this?  Presumably Sheldon will try to choose the "best" possible three numbers and Leonard will then try to arrange them in the "worst" way.  No probability involved.

Comment: Incorrect. Sheldon picks ANY THREE real numbers, randomly, not by choice. Hence the involvement of probability

Comment: And what about Leonard? Does he arrange at random either?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  A:  There is no uniform distribution on the reals so you need to specify what distribution Sheldon uses.  B (more important):  by counting arguments Sheldon has no hope.

Comment: Counting arguments:  only countably many quadratics have rational roots, but there are uncountably many real quadratics.

Comment: @Mostafa Ayaz, as long as it's not mentioned; that's what I believe. Also, I've edited the question- they've asked the maximum probability of winning and not just the probability.

Comment: I think the problem is more interesting if you remove the probability.  Is there any triple of non-zero reals such that all $6$ possible quadratics have distinct rational roots?  (that already seems unlikely to me).

Comment: For what it's worth:  my guess is the question was meant to ask "Suppose Sheldon chooses a triple of non-zero real numbers (not probabilistically).  Leonard then chooses one of the $6$ associated quadratics uniformly at random.  What is the maximal probability for a Sheldon win?"  Note that Sheldon can certainly achieve $\frac 16$.  Can Sheldon do any better than that?

Comment: Since lulu explains above that the probability of Sheldon winning is zero when he picks the coefficients randomly, we are left with two possible interesting questions: the one in the PS and a version where Sheldon picks his real numbers as smart as possible but Lennard arranges them completely random with each of the six arrangement having equal probability. In this case the question 'what is the maximum probability for Sheldon to win' makes the most sense, especially when the answer to the question in the PS is "no".

Comment: ha, lulu typed the same thing as I did at the same time. I really think this is the most interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the triple $(-3,2,1)$.  Then each of the $6$ polynomials that can be formed with these coefficients has two distinct rational roots.  Thus Sheldon can assure a victory by choosing this triple.

This is easily checked by hand.  To speed the calculation, note that $ax^2+bx+c$ has two distinct rational roots iff $cx^2+bx+a$ does (trusting that none of the coefficients are $0$).  Thus there are really only three polynomials to check.

Answer (score 0):

It's 0%, Leonard cant win if Sheldon chooses right numbers.

To have two distinct rational solutions delta must be greater than 0, which means b2 - 4ac > 0    =>     b2 > 4ac
If Sheldon chooses 10  -1 -2 , he wins. b2 is always greater than 0, so a*c can't be negative, therefore a and b have to be -1 and -2.
100 > 8, Sheldon wins.

Comment: You have ignored the "rational" part of "distinct rational roots".

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to verify the determinant of the second degree equation. You have that $ax^2+bx+c=0$ will have two distinct solution if and only if $\Delta=\sqrt{b^2-4ac}>0$. Hence what you are looking for is when $b^2-4ac>0$.

Comment: You have ignored the "rational" part of "distinct rational solutions".

Comment: True hahahahaha. Sorry I missed out this part